# PyCharm/Python don't import packages from Anaconda

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, conda

I am using PyCharm as IDE and Anaconda as a package manager. Pyhton is `3.6 version`

When I `import pandas` I get

```
pyptz: No moudle name 'pyptz'
dateutil: No moudle name 'dateutil'
```

However in PyCharm interpreter I have all these packages are updated.

Another problem, I don't know if it is related, is I have `pip 20.0.2`   however in the command line (that is in the same directory of my Python console) it says my `pip version` is `9.0.1`

It seems that no matter if I have my packages in anaconda up to date, those packages do not interact with PyCharm/Python.

PS: I also have my /PATH with the Anaconda directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your PyCharm project
2. Go to `File>Settings`. Then `Project:[YOUR_PROJECT_NAME]>Project Interpreter`
3. After that, you'll see the image below
4. Choose your `Anaconda Interpreter` from the list
5. If you don't find it in the list, the go-to `Show All ...` and select your Interpreter.
6. `Apply` and `Save` the Settings

[image: Pycharm Project Interpreter Settings]

Comment: What if my interpreter has no Anaconda logo, but instead only a python logo?

Comment: That's not a problem. You just have to ensure the location of your `Anaconda Interpreter`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by reinstall the Anaconda Software in C:/Users/"User name"/AppData/Local

I am not sure if it is because the pip folder is in this directory, but I tested a lot of solutions, and this is the only one that worked.